# Where can I find Endrega embryos?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I found the recipe for Enhanced Thunderbolt quite a while ago, but I'm still missing one particular ingredient, the Endrega embryos.

I've killed several Endregas in the meantime, but none have dropped an embryo. It doesn't look like I'll just stumble upon them any time soon, so I'm now trying to find where exactly I should look.

Which Endregas actually drop this item? Only a particular type like Warriors, or does this somehow depend on the monster level? And where can I find enough of the correct type of Endrega to finally get some Endrega embryos?

Answer (score 6):

Endrega Workers drop Endrega Embryo's (as well as Endrega hearts, Venom extract and Chitin scales).

Endrega workers can normally be found travelling in small groups (6+) in and around caves and abandoned structures in Velen and Skellige.

Comment: Are you sure about that second part?  I thought deconstruct let you destroy an endrega embryo in order to get a monster egg and a monster essence.  It's not possible to go the other way.

Comment: @aroth oh yeh I think you're right I got it the other way around

Comment: Ok, so where do I find Endrega Workers?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft updated answer